# Securing FTP Access On Solaris 10

Tags: security, ssh, ftp, solaris, solaris-10

I have a web server (running Apache on Solaris 10) that I look after for some friends and I was wondering how to restrict each users FTP/SSH access.
I want each account when they login to be taken straight to their home directory, and not be allowed above it.
I have tried changing the permission on the folder above the users home directories to not allow the 'other' group, but this resulted in commands like *cd* and *ls* not working.
I have read about the *chroot* command, but from what I have read it scares me.
Any help or guidenance is gratefully received.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chroot is the standard way to lock ftp user accounts into a completely controlled environment.  It is not scary at all - basically what you do is create a 'mini' envrionment where the user can see only certain directories, with a custom /usr directory. The special /usr has only a few files in it.

There are a series of "control" files in /etc/ftpd:
ftpaccess       ftpconversions  ftpgroups       ftphosts        ftpservers      ftpusers

Have a look at each file, plus there is a man page for them, ie `man -s 4 ftpuser`